# In Nuxt, how to mutate a Vuex state in one module from the other?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, store, vuex-modules

I tried many things mentioned on the portal but nothing seems to work for me so posting here for some work-around.

I have 2 modules within my `Nuxtjs` application folder `store\modules`: `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`. For some verification in `ModuleB` I would like to access the `state` from `ModuleA` but for some reason, it's failing.

I tried `rootScope`, `import` etc but it did not work for me.

My `state/modules/ModuleA.js`:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  eventType: 'MyEvent',
})

export const mutations = {
  eventTypePopulator (state, event) {
    state.eventType = event
  },
}
```

My `state/modules/ModuleB.js`:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  input: {}
})

export const mutations = {
  jsonPreparation ({state, rootState}, payload) {
    console.log(rootState.eventType)
    // console.log($store.state.ModuleA.eventType)
  }
}
```

I tried to import `ModuleA` into `ModuleB` and use it but that also did not work for me. Can someone please help me how can I access the `state` from one `Module` in another `Module` within `Nuxtjs/Vuejs`

Comment: Are those modules namespaced or not?

Comment: @kissu Thanks a lot for your response. I have not used any `namespacing` while creating these modules. I just created a folder `modules` under `store` and then created different files such as `ModuleA.js` and `ModuleB.js`. What is the benefit of doing namespacing? Will it resolve my issue?

Comment: Btw, did you mean `store/modules/ModuleA.js`?

Comment: Namespacing is nice if you want to get more organized mainly. More info can be found here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing This will not solve the issue by itself but it's something that you need to take into account. Nuxt uses namespacing by default for it's modules as shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#modules I do usually make my own namespacing so I'm not sure but my answer should probably be somewhat close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [API reference](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions), `rootState` is available in `actions` and `getters`.
It did not found any way of using it **directly** into a `mutation`.

Meanwhile, this can be achieved by passing it as a param to the `mutation` like this

`ModuleB.js`

```js
const mutations = {
  NICE_TASTY_MUTATION: (_state, { rootState, payload }) => {
    // _state is not used here because it's moduleB's local state
    rootState['moduleA'].eventType = payload
  },
}

const actions = {
  async myCoolAction({ commit, rootState }, { ...}) {
    commit('NICE_TASTY_MUTATION', {
      rootState,
      payload: 'some-stuff'
    })
  }
}
```

And this could be called in a `.vue` file with something like this

```js
methods: {
  ...mapActions('ModuleB', ['myCoolAction']),
}

...
await this.myCoolAction()
```

---

PS: IMO the convention is more to name the file `module_b.js`.

Comment: Hi, If you get a chance can you please have a look at this question and provide some solution if possible? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69182804/7584240 Thanks a lot in advance.