# Vuejs and HTML creating a complex JSON Object dynamically and displaying the same to user using V-for

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, dynamic

I am developing a `Vuejs` application within which I have a field. For this field, users can provide the values and this field expands dynamically based on the user-provided values.

The field name is `extensions`, initially an `Add Extension` button will be displayed. With on click of the button, a bootstrap modal will be displayed which has 3 fields: `namespace (text), localname (text), datatype(dropdown: string/complex)`. If the `datatype` is `string` then a simple text field will be displayed. However, if the `datatype` is `complex` then another button should be displayed and with on click of the button again the same modal is displayed with fields and the process continues. So the created JSON based on this will expand horizontally and vertically.

I am able to complete the first iteration and display the elements to users on the front end. However, for further iteration, I am not understanding how to achieve it using the recursive approach. Since I don't know how many times users may create the extensions I need to have an approach that dynamically does this.

Can someone please help me how to create and display the JSONarray using Vuejs which expands horizontally and vertically?

Following is the code I have so far:

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <span>Extensions</span>
        <button class="form-control" @click="createExtensions()">
          Add Another
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div v-for="extension in extensionList" :key="extension.ID" class="form-inline">
      <span>{{ extension.namespace+ ":"+extension.localName }}</span>
      <input v-if="extension.dataType == 'string'" type="text" @input="AddExtensionText($event,extension.ID)">
      <button v-if="extension.dataType == 'complex'" @click="AddComplextExtension(extension.ID)">
        Add another
      </button>
    </div>

    <b-modal
      id="Extension"
      title="Add Another Element"
      size="lg"
      width="100%"
      :visible="showModal"
    >
      <b-form id="AddExtension" @submit.prevent="submitExtension">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Namespace URI:</label>
          <input
            v-model="extension.namespace"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            required
          >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Local Name:</label>
          <input
            v-model="extension.localName"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            required
          >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="AddExtensionDataType" class="col-form-label">Data Type:</label>
          <b-form-select v-model="extension.dataType" class="form-control">
            <b-form-select-option value="string">
              String
            </b-form-select-option>
            <b-form-select-option value="complex">
              Complex
            </b-form-select-option>
          </b-form-select>
        </div>
      </b-form>
      <template #modal-footer="{ cancel }">
        <b-btn @click="cancel">
          Cancel
        </b-btn>
        <b-btn variant="primary" type="submit" form="AddExtension">
          OK
        </b-btn>
      </template>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      extensionList: [],
      extensionCount: 0,
      extension: {
        namespace: '',
        localName: '',
        dataType: 'string'
      },
      showModal: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // Method to create extensions and add
    createExtensions () {
      this.showModal = true
    },

    // Function to submit the each extension
    submitExtension () {
      this.showModal = false
      const extensionObj = {}
      extensionObj.ID = this.extensionCount
      extensionObj.namespace = this.extension.namespace
      extensionObj.localName = this.extension.localName
      extensionObj.dataType = this.extension.dataType
      this.extensionList.push(extensionObj)
      this.extensionCount++
    },

    // On addition of the input field value update List
    AddExtensionText (event, extensionID) {
      const extension = this.extensionList.filter(ex => ex.ID === extensionID)[0]
      if (typeof extension !== 'undefined') {
        extension.text = (typeof event.target.value !== 'undefined') ? event.target.value : ''
      }
    },

    // Add complex extension
    AddComplextExtension (extensionID) {
      this.showModal = true
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

This is the initial field I have:

[image]

This is what I want to achieve where everything is created dynamically and JSON expands both horizontally and vertically:

[image]

Can someone please let me know how to create such dynamic JSON using Vuejs and display the same in the frontend.

Comment: Try this solution https://github.com/jinkin1995/vue-json-edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display data recursively, you need to use recursive components.

Abstract your `v-for` code into another component file (let's call it `NodeComponent.vue`). Pass your `extensionList` to this component, then inside this component, add another `NodeComponent` for each `extension` which has type `complex`.

Since your `extension` would be another array if it is `complex`, you can pass it directly into this `NodeComponent` as a prop and let recursion work its magic.

NodeComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="extension in extensionList"
      :key="extension.ID"
      class="form-inline"
    >
      <span>{{ extension.namespace + ":" + extension.localName }}</span>
      <input
        v-if="extension.dataType == 'string'"
        type="text"
        @input="$emit('AddExtensionText', {$event, id: extension.ID}"
      />
      <NodeComponent v-if="extention.dataType == 'complex'" :extentionList="extension" @AddExtensionText="AddExtensionText($event)"/>
      <button
        v-if="extension.dataType == 'complex'"
        @click="AddComplextExtension(extension.ID)"
      >
        Add another
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    extensionList: Array,
    extension: Object,
  },
  methods: {
    AddComplextExtension(extensionID) {
      // Emit event on root to show modal, or use this.$bvModal.show('modal-id') or create a dynamic modal, see: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#message-box-advanced-usage
    }
    AddExtensionText({ value, id }) {
      const i = this.extensionList.findIndex((el) => el.ID === id);
      this.$set(extensionList, i, value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Note that I emit a custom event from child `NodeComponent`s on changing input text so that the parent can make this change in its `extensionList` array, using `this.$set` to maintain reactivity.

**EDIT**: If you want to add new Node components:

You need to have a parent component that holds the first NodeComponent in it. In here you'll define the modal (if you define it inside NodeComponent, you'll have a separate modal reference for each NodeComponent. Judging from your code you're probably using Bootstrap-Vue, it injects modals lazily when shown, so I don't think this will affect your performance too much, but it still doesn't feel like good code.). You need to emit event on root to show the modal. You need to send the `extensionList` as payload with this event like this: `this.$root.emit('showModal', extensionList)`. In you parent component you can listen to the event and show the modal.  Now inside your `submitExtension` function, you can use this `extensionList` and push a new object to it. The corresponding NodeComponent will update itself since arrays are passed by reference.

```
this.$root.on('showModal`, (extensionList) => {
    this.editExtensionList = extensionList;
    showModal = true;
}
```

```
    submitExtension() {
      this.showModal = false
      const extensionObj = {}
      extensionObj.ID = this.extensionCount
      extensionObj.namespace = this.extension.namespace
      extensionObj.localName = this.extension.localName
      extensionObj.dataType = this.extension.dataType
      this.editExtensionList.push(extensionObj)
      this.extensionCount++
    }
```

All being said, at this point it might be worthwhile to invest in implementing a [VueX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-a-state-management-pattern) store where you have a global extentionList and define mutations to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. This is what I am looking for and it's working fine. But I am unable to create the complex `extensionList`. How do I add the elements to `inner child extensionList`. I am a bit confused about how to create the complex `extensionList` after providing the data. Can you please provide some suggestions for adding information to complex `extensionList`?

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 Check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and response. Based on your response I moved the `extensionList` to `Vuex` and trying to access it from there. But for some reason, it still does not work for me as expected. I have posted the project which you can run and test: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-wildflower-5f7x9?file=/pages/index.vue:0-574

Comment: I hope you are aware of what I am looking for based on the question and samples I have provided. If you get a chance can you please have a look at the sample and provide me some guidance on how can I make my code work and handle the data dynamically and display the same to the users? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Cool that you made a sandbox, makes things a lot easier. I'll fork it post a link of working sandbox in a while.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 You were quite close. But you made it more complicated than it had to be. [Here's the working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-smoke-h9xx3?file=/store/index.js). Let me know if you want clarification on something.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response and willingness to help me with this issue. I am looking into your response and trying to incorporate them into my application. I will let you know if it's working or if I run into some issue :)

Comment: You are awesome, thanks a lot for your response. Everything is working as expected. I have added the modify, deletion, and capturing of the text field value based on changes within my application. Everything seems to work as expected. Thanks again for helping me with the issue. Have a great day :)

Comment: Always glad to help, great day to you too :)